# Не подключается Jquery к Bitrix 1C

Tags: jquery, битрикс

Подскажите , не могу ни как понять , почему не вешается JQuery на  Bitrix. Залил css, оно подключилось как надо, заливаю JS Он не хочет подключаться

Вот само подключение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее спасибо

Comment: А зачем это делать если в Битрикс есть уже Jquery готовый который подключается сам автоматически?

Comment: Не работают элементы без подключенного Jquery.